# Error message only when running the app on real smart TV

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to develop a samsung smart tv app, which so far works quite well on Samsung SDK's emulator (I am using version 3.5.2), however when I sync my app on a smart tv, the result is not the same as running at emulator.

For example, at scene A, when I press button left, I suppose to navigate to scene B, which works as expected in emulator.

However at the real smart tv, when I press button left, nothing happens, and the log has a strange error message: `cannot run current focused scene's key handler.`

I have searched the official Samsung development forum but seems not many people face this problem, anyone can help and tell me why I get this error and how can I solve it ?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the focus to the new scene that you want to be active.
For example `scene2.focus()`
Also you should update the SDK, 3.5 is quite old! Try using Samsung SDK 4.5